# When does the .csproj file get updated?

Tags: c#, .net

I open my solution file in VS2010, right click on a project,  go to the build tab and switch the .NET framework from (say) 4 to 2.  Then I do a save all.  But my .csproj doesn't change - it still says

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Why is this?  And what do I have to do to get this line to update?

Comment: Have you tried closing the project and restarting it?

Comment: You say you go to the build tab - are you sure about this? The place to select your target framework is on the application tab.

Comment: Do you have different build configurations that target different frameworks?  As @bemused shows, the target framework option is on the Applicaiton tab, curious as to what you are doing on the build tab, might be a clue.

Comment: Root cause - multiple projects within a single solution, and clicking "Properties" on a different project.

Comment: @Scott, Doh! It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on your project from within VS2010, select Properties and set the Target framework to .NET Framework 2.0. VS will close/reopen the app and you should be good to go. I'm not sure what you mean by *to go build* but you shouldn't have to explicitly click *Save All*.

[image]

Comment: Sorry - should have been "go to build (tab)" - corrected.  But I'm doing this and the .csproj still isn't getting updated.  I know my local build will use .NET2, but I need to share this file.

Comment: +1 Tested this on my machine, csproj changes after selecting yes on the dialog box warning you that VS is about to close/reopen.

Comment: @Scott, What do you mean you know your local build will use .NET2? If you set the target framework correctly it'll be true for everyone who opens the project. There is no user specific option here.

Comment: @Scott, yes. If you follow the above steps in bemused's answer, it would. What are you doing, step by step? Explain in your question. =)

Comment: Ack - @bemused was correct - the issue was that there were two projects in the solution and I was clicking on the wrong one.  Clicking on the right one and resetting the .NET framework does update the .csproj.